# Can I use one tarsnap cache for multiple keys?

Tags: tarsnap

The semantics of the tarsnap cache are unclear. I know that the tarsnap cache directory is used to determine what is duplicated data and what needs to be sent over the wire, but can all keys share the same cache directory or is there a one-to-one mapping between keys and cache dirs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share one key amongst several data sources, but each data source should have its own cache. [You, theoretically, you could share a cache but the way tarsnap is designed doesn't support this well.](http://mail.tarsnap.com/tarsnap-users/msg00624.html)